CSS Flip Card Scroll Issue in Firefox: Scrollbar Appears but doesn't work with mouse wheel
If I made a flip card like the one here flip_card, but and made the front-card and the back-card scrollable then the scrolling via mouse wheel only works with the back-card and the front-card only works if I clicked directly on the scrollbar and move it up or down.
This is only happens in firefox.
Here is a modified version of the above flip card that demonstrate the issue clearly:


function rotate() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("flip-card-inner")[0].style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)"
}

function rotateBack() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("flip-card-inner")[0].style.transform = "rotateY(0)"
}
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: auto;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
<h1>Card Flip with Text</h1>
<h3>Hover over the image below:</h3>
<button onclick="rotate()">Flib</button>
<button onclick="rotateBack()">Flib back</button>
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



The front-card scrollbar will only work if the back is hidden(display:none).
So why this is only happening in firefox? and why I need to hide it since the back-card is already has transform: rotateY(180deg) property?
Thank you.

The problem is that you place two divs on top of each other. So the one with the higher z-index will receive the pointer events. The rotation affects the rendering only and not the actual order in the DOM. You could change their z-index when you flip them or disable the pointer-events on the side that is facing the back.
It is easier if you handle the flip by toggling a class instead of rotating it through the style.
So adding the .flipped class on the card and you can now handle the functionality through CSS with
.flip-card:not(.flipped) .flip-card-back {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.flip-card.flipped .flip-card-front {
  pointer-events: none;
}

So a working example would be something like


function rotate() {
  document.querySelector('.flip-card').classList.toggle('flipped');
}
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card.flipped .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: auto;
}

.flip-card:not(.flipped) .flip-card-back {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.flip-card.flipped .flip-card-front {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
<h1>Card Flip with Text</h1>
<h3>Hover over the image below:</h3>
<button onclick="rotate()">Flip</button>
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
      <h1>FRONT</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>BACK</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Thanks for the clarification about what the pointer event, Now I understand what is the issue and why this is happening with the flip card, but why only with Firefox? In another word why google chrome does not have the same behaviour? Thank you.
